# Can some please explain what this query is doing

Tags: sql-server

My intention is to find top rows without using rownumber,top,limit,offshet in SQL. So i found this query but I am unable to understand this. so kindly help on this. it would be good if you can give step by steps that how it will be executing.

Query:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Name FROM Table t
WHERE 10 > (SELECT count(*) FROM Table t2 WHERE t.id > t2.id)
```

Comment: That looks like the most pointless bit of SQL I've seen in a while, it would appear to be selecting the top 10 rows from the table.

Comment: _without using rownumber, top, ..._ Why? Why is your goal to avoid using the obvious and native tsql (and sql AFAIK) solution that has already been optimized into the database engine code?

Comment: This is a massively inefficient way of getting the top 10 rows. It has quadratic complexity. If the table has 10 million rows it will end up evaluating `49,999,995,000,000` rows from the sub query. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-triangular-joins#menu-item-15:~:text=%3C%20or%20%3E%20%22Inequality%22%20Triangular%20Join - and that is assuming there is an index to allow the `t.id > t2.id` predicate to be seeked

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple

The first part selects rows from table `t`.

The criteria is a little confusing but also means

`where (value) <10`

The correlated query counts rows in the table for each row, and only where the current `id` value is greater than the previous value.

you can visualise that better if you change it slightly to

```
select * from (
    select t.Id, t.Name, (SELECT count(*) FROM Table t2 WHERE t.id > t2.id) qty
    from Table t
)x
WHERE qty <10
```

You'll see each Id gets a count in ascending order and it's filtered to only return the first 10 (counts 0-9)

It's the same as `select top 10 from table order by Id`

Except it will counting the rows in the table increasing each time with each successive row and will probably be a performance nightmare.

Don't do this!